# gitignore how to unignore Makefile

Tags: git, gitignore

How to unignore Makefile, the name of my Makefile is `Makefile`, I tried this:

```
*
!Makefile
```

but my Makefile is always ignored.

Comment: That should work, try running `git check-ignore -v *` to see your ignored files along with the associated ignore rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I met the same problem before, what I did is using little m instead: `!makefile`, and change the name of the make file to `makefile`. Don't know why, but just worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You might have introduced a trailing whitespace. Just look for spaces after the line `!Makefile`. Other than that I do not see a reason for your file getting ignored.